# system restart on alienware mx17 maxed my harddrive

Tags: ssd, hard-drive-recovery

I did a full factory restore to my alienware mx17 when windows was reinstalled from factory disk it took up around 170 GB of my 225 GB SSD drive any answers on whey this would be?

Answer (score 0):

It probably does this because since you are doinga "Factory" restore not an actual reinstallation of the OS, it is keeping all the software which comes standard with the Alienware laptops such as DELL support tools. So if you want to actually remove everything you will need to use a windows disk to completely remove everything.

Comment: That may account for about 1Gb, but not 170...

Comment: Right, I Missed that part. If you use http://www.jgoodies.com/ this tool, it gives you a Piechart graph showing where the space is being allocated around your Laptop, so using that it can give you a pretty good idea where the space is being held.

Comment: I sust went through disk drive it shows a folder "windows old" taking up aproximatly 100GB can I empty windows old folder and save this space ?

Comment: ok i see what has happened, the "windows.old" folder is basically the old files from the previous installation so deleting that is fine.

Comment: ok I appreciate the help

Comment: no problem! dont forget to REP/upvote